# use rewrite to hide add to cart button magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm learning magento. And i'm finding out about hide add to cart button using rewrite, but i could not find any tutorials on internet. Is there any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For hiding addtocart button you need to do

Removing from product page you need to create local.xml under 'app/design/frontend/themepackage/theme/layout/' and put the below xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="product.info.addtocart"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Remove from category page

Go to your list.phtml under 'app/design/frontend/themepackage/theme/template/catalog/product' there will be button with label 'Add to Cart' it will be for grid and list view both so find it in file and comment it.

Answer (score 0):

I am recommend to you please read this guide from Magento:

https://magento.com/sites/default/files/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf

It will give you overview on customizing the Magento front-end.